# Task chaining in Firebase Unity, how to avoid code pyramid?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, task

Supposed I have to get login information from the server then login, then after the login do something next. The goal is to encapsulate all of this into something that caller can wait.

However each of Firebase C# API call already returned separate tasks (that has already been started). My approach is to think of how to chain each of these separate task together.

I am thinking of making a new `Task` that represent this since it also seems great for aggregating all the exceptions for the caller to catch.

We have

`Task<DataSnapshot> getKeyTask  = Database.Child("keyLocation").GetValueAsync();`

`GetValueAsync` as I understand already spun up the task. We can observe the returned task or better use continuation to begin something when it finished.

`Task loginTask = Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(username, password);`

`Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` also spun up a **new** task in itself. I can also use continuation to wait and begin something else.

After the login I would like to use another database call to get user data.

So

```
public Task Login()
{
    Task<DataSnapshot> getKeyTask = Database.Child("keyLocation").GetValueAsync();

    Task loginAfterGetKeyTask = getKeyTask.ContinueWith(gkt =>
    {
        Task loginTask = Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(gkt.Result.___.username, gkt.Result.____.password);
        loginTask.ContinueWith(lt => { ....the next task.... });
    });

    return loginAfterGetKeyTask;
}
```

There are 2 problems I found :

1. As it goes on the code is getting deeper in the pyramid. Is there any way I can do to make the code looks more sequential?
2. This `Login()` function I want to return a `Task` so that caller can wait for the whole login process to finish then continue, etc. But currently the returned `loginAfterGetKey` task finished even if there are more things to do inside. I could keep doing `.ContinueWith` chaining on the outside if not for that there are one more Firebase task that is executed. Ideally I would like to return the `Task` that represent the whole thing but they are nested inside. Firebase's method start those task on it's own so I think I could not try to bundle all the task on my own.

I tried encapsulate all the tasks as a new Task start from `Task.Factory.StartNew` however "GetComponent can only be called from main thread" is a problem. (The `Auth` and other Firebase service would require `GetComponent`)

I tried using `IEnumerator` as a return of `Login()` and planned to put `yield` in this function, however, "The yield statement cannot be used inside anonymous method or lambda expression".

I tried using `loginTask.Wait()` inside the first `ContinueWith` in order to make `loginAfterGetKeyTask` that I return from this function not arrive at `IsCompleted` state until it reacehs the end (which would have to wait for the tasks inside) but since the lambda in this `ContinueWith` is in the main thread, it causes deadlock.

Comment: So why not use `async/await`?

Comment: I have read about them but unfortunately Unity's C# version cannot use those keywords.

Comment: Oh ok I did not know that.

Comment: what do you want to do in the calling code with the `Task` which you return from `Login`? will you wait on it synchronously (`.Wait` call) or asynchronously (`.ContinueWith`)?

Comment: Currently one of the use is from an integration test which will wait for the login synchronously then test the credentials returned. However from that test I could not use `.Wait` as it will deadlock, but I can also do it synchronously by yielding the returned `Task` until its `IsComplete` becomes true then continue to the check. (repeatedly check for the task every frame)

Comment: *PS : With Unity 2017.1 onwards if you turn on .NET 4.5 experimental in the  settings you can now use `async/await`

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used `IEnumerator` loop waiting as a kind of hack to wait for the `Task` to finish. It 'linearize' the `Task` multi-thread system into single thread coroutine system that Unity seems to prefer. Each `yield return null` results in resuming in the next frame to check on the `Task`'s status again.

Not very elegant but I could not find any better way outside `async/await` that pairs with `Task` but Unity's C# version does not yet support it.

```
public void Caller()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(Login());
    // Login finished, check the login credentials
}

private IEnumerator WaitTask(Task task)
{
    while (task.IsCompleted == false)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    if(task.IsFaulted)
    {
        throw task.Exception;
    }
}

public IEnumerator Login()
{
    Task<DataSnapshot> getKeyTask = Database.Child("keyLocation").GetValueAsync();

    yield return WaitTask(getKeyTask);

    Task loginTask = Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(getKeyTask.Result.___.username, getKeyTask.Result.____.password);

    yield return WaitTask(loginTask);

    //... the next task can use loginTask.Result etc.

}
```

It would be tricky still to catch exception since compiler does not allow `try catch` to wrap the `yield`. One way I might use the callback pattern to send the exception to the caller.

Here's an extension version in case you want to do like `yield return task.YieldWait();` instead.

```
public static class TaskExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Firebase Task might not play well with Unity's Coroutine workflow. You can now yield on the task with this.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerator YieldWait(this Task task)
    {
        while (task.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        if(task.IsFaulted)
        {
            throw task.Exception;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're now checking the status of the task on every single frame, unlike the original code, which doesn't do anything at all while the async operation is going on.